# How to find out which fonts are referenced and which are embedded in a PDF document

Tags: pdf, fonts

We have a little problem with fonts in PDF documents. In order to put the finger on the problem I'd like to inspect, which fonts are actually embedded in the pdf document and which are only referenced. Is there an easy (and cheap as in free) way to do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I finally got an example file that actually seems to have fonts embedded.

Using the normal Adobe Reader (or Foxit if you prefer). Select File->Properties on the resulting Dialog choose the Font tab. You will see a list of fonts. The ones that are embedded will state this fact in ( ) behind the font name.

Comment: Does this tab exist in the Mac version? I can't find it, I have a Mac ) :

Answer (score 194):

`pdffonts` command line tool originally from [Xpdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpdf), now part of [Poppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)).

This tool is available in most Linux distributions as part of `poppler-utils` package.

Example usage and output:

```
$ pdffonts some.pdf 

name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
BAAAAA+Arial-Black                   TrueType          yes yes yes     53  0
CAAAAA+Tahoma                        TrueType          yes yes yes     28  0
DAAAAA+Wingdings-Regular             TrueType          yes yes yes     43  0
EAAAAA+Webdings                      TrueType          yes yes yes     38  0
FAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          yes yes yes     33  0
GAAAAA+Tahoma-Bold                   TrueType          yes yes yes     23  0
HAAAAA+OpenSymbol                    TrueType          yes yes yes     48  0
```

Comment: to avoid linkrot, please include an example and/or some doc.

Comment: It seems to have been installed by default on my Lubuntu 14.10 installation.

Comment: For mac users, `brew install poppler` to easily get the `pdffonts` command

Comment: In evince document viewer, go to File --> properties --> Fonts tab

Comment: Note: on Windows, pdffonts can be installed as part of the Poppler chocolatey package https://chocolatey.org/packages/poppler

Comment: Veery late to the party, but is there a way to extract the font size as well in a similar way?

Comment: `pdffonts file.pdf | cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq -d`

Answer (score 98):

Many PDFs include the font names in plain text.

To check this in Unix/Linux/macOS, run this from a terminal:

```
strings yourPDFfilepath.pdf | grep FontName
```

Comment: Windows: findstr FontName yourPDFfilepath.pdf

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  (Mac with PDF generated by latex.)  `pdffonts` shows two embedded fonts; this shows none.  Evidently, this method works some times, but is not reliable.

Comment: try with lowercase f on fontName

Comment: @texnic Try this. Right click and open the file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad) and search for FontName.

Comment: `FontName` wasn't found in a PDF I just tried. Just looking for `grep -i font` gave : `/BaseFont /Helvetica`

Answer (score 5):

[CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) has a font reporter, available as a command-line utility or via a library call.  If you run "listfont.pl file.pdf" you get output like this:

```
Page 1:
  Name: F1.0
    Type: TrueType
    BaseFont: NZUXSR+Impact
    Encoding: MacRomanEncoding
    Widths: yes
      Characters: 0-255
    Embedded: yes
  Name: F2.0
    Type: TrueType
    BaseFont: XSFKRA+ArialMT
    Encoding: MacRomanEncoding
    Widths: yes
      Characters: 0-255
    Embedded: yes
```