# How to modify tiff creation date in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, image-manipulation, tiff

I am writing a [pdf comparison utility](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification). After [some investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897806/why-would-pdfs-generated-by-the-same-automated-process-be-different-on-different) it seems like the best way to do this is to convert to tiff and compare from there.

I managed to do this with Ghostscript but am getting a difference in the embedded *creation date* metadata.

[image: different creation dates embedded in tiff]

How do I use .Net to modify this?

Comment: Does the creation date have a fixed offset from the top of the file? If so, I would overwrite one with the value of the other.

Comment: @wilsotc I have no idea and I'm hoping to get a recommendation for a library or BCL class that actually has some insight into the tiff file structure rather than brute forcing it with string processing

Comment: Have you tried: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.inplacebitmapmetadatawriter(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @wilsotc I've tried the BitmapMetadata class. Interestingly it [reads the application name part](http://screencast.com/t/CIsMruGITcc) but not the date

Comment: Please put the TIFF somewhere I can download it. I may have a solution.

Comment: Do you want the code in c#, or vb?

Comment: @wilsotc I guess I prefer c# but it doesn't really matter - I can translate perfectly well from one to the other

Comment: @wilsotc Here you go - [here's a tiff](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification/blob/pdf-image-verification/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification.Tests/PdfVerificationTests.can_use_image_approval_mode.approved.tiff) in my repo. That should give you some context for what I'm doing as well

Comment: Heh. I once solved this type of problem by writing a StreamReader wrapper class that detected such date stamps and replaced them by empty data on the fly while reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LibTiff.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/). It is open source. Using this library, you can use the [SetField method](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/tiff.setfield.aspx) to modify any one of the many [tags](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/well-known-tags-and-their-value%28s%29-data-types.aspx) in the Tiff file, including the TiffTag.DATETIME flag.

Comment: This is also a good solution. The only downside is adding another library to the project.

Comment: @wilsotc -- Maybe he could look at the source code and see how they do it?

Comment: Yipes. Any idea how to actually use `SetField`? the code `using(var tiff = Tiff.Open(destination.FullName, "w")) tiff.SetField(TiffTag.DATETIME, "2010:01:01 12:00:00");` hopelessly mangled my Tiff file. Matter of fact opening the file for write at all seems to do this

Comment: using `"rw"` for the mode fixes the mangling issue, but the date time field is still not being set

Comment: Ok, so upon further experimentation "rw" is simply the same as "r". I've tried using "a" but the output is still unchanged. Could you maybe post a code snippet?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer -- Honestly, I haven't used the library. But if you can post the TIF file you are using somewhere, I can try to put together a quick sample.

Comment: Already posted in the comments above. [Here it is again](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification/blob/pdf-image-verification/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification.Tests/PdfVerificationTests.can_use_image_approval_mode.approved.tiff) and thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, got it. The trick is to `SetDirectory` [like in this example](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/add-custom-tiff-tags-to-an-existing-tiff-image.aspx). Apparently a directory is a page and you need to iterate through them.

Comment: [Here's the solution](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification/blob/c32075db83be3caf7b050086380871a2bab95e9d/ApprovalTests.BetterPdfVerification/PdfApprovals.cs#L71)

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, it seems Microsoft does provide a TIFF library with multi-image support. It's in System.Windows.Media.Imaging. To get this namespace reference PresentationCore.

To access the TIFF metadata use this site as a reference: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/baseline.html

This code accesses the date field after the GhostScript name you were interested in:

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\PdfVerificationTests.can_use_image_approval_mode.approved.tiff");
    FileStream stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.None);
    TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    BitmapMetadata bmd = (BitmapMetadata) decoder.Frames[0].Metadata;
    string thedateval = (string) bmd.GetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=306}");
    BitmapMetadata bmd2 = bmd.Clone();
    bmd2.SetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=306}", "2013:05:30 20:07:52");
```

This code does *not* write out a modified TIFF, but is all the info you need to do so. Hope this helps as I feel I'm beating a dead horse.

This code will strip all the attributes from a multipage TIFF and leave the image content intact:

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\PdfVerificationTests.can_use_image_approval_mode.approved.tiff");
    FileStream stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    FileStream stream2 = new FileStream("empty.tif", FileMode.Create);
    TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
    for (int i = 0; i < decoder.Frames.Count(); i++)
    {
        BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[i];
        int stride = source.PixelWidth * (source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
        byte[] data = new byte[stride * source.PixelHeight];
        source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
        CachedBitmap theSource = (CachedBitmap)BitmapSource.Create(source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight, source.DpiX, source.DpiY, source.Format, source.Palette, data, stride);
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(theSource));
    }
    try
    {
        encoder.Save(stream2);
        stream2.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Comment: For posterity as we discussed this in a different venue: the problem with this approach is that it kills off many advantages of tiffs (such as multipage support). Forming back to a tiff then might still have a creation date, just a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If the date stamps are fixed size, a fun workaround for this type of problem is to write a `FileStream` which simply detects and blanks out such date stamps. In fact I've done this before for PDF comparison, on a project I worked on in school. The checksum comparison worked fine with just that, without any conversion to tiff, though in our specific case we were sure all compared PDFs were generated by the same system, so that simplified things a bit.

The basic method is to make a subclass of `FileStream` with overridden `ReadByte` and `Read` functions, which contains the length and expected format of the date stamps. Whenever a read is performed the following happens:

- The code reads an extra piece, the size of the datestamp length minus 1 byte, both before and behind the requested data.
- Inside that block, a search and replace is performed to clear any found date stamps.
- Finally, the original requested piece is returned.

The source code I wrote for the project back in the day is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/lmsda/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/DokeosUpload/persistence/document/PDFFilterFileStream.cs).

Answer (score 0):

It seams that this ghostscript behavior could be supressed.

> -dTIFFDateTime=false

https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Devices.htm

... but for this situation I would recommend some diffpdf tools (http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/diffpdf)

D